# Bot framework composer not able to publish to Azure LUIS error

Tags: azure, bots, token, azure-language-understanding

Is it something wrong with LUIS server? Can anyone help? it's working fine yesterday and today it's just not working suddenly.

The error was attached below:

---

### "{"name":"StatusCodeError","statusCode":400,"message":"400 - {\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadArgument\",\"message\":\"Failed to parse azure account information object object.\"}}","error":{"error":{"message":"Failed to parse azure account information object object."}},"options":{},"response":{"statusCode":400},"stack":"StatusCodeError: 400 - {\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadArgument\",\"message\":\"Failed to parse azure account information object object.\"}}\n    at new i (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:338:110597)\n    at F.callback (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:338:109440)\n    at F.e.callback.t.callback [as _callback] (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:338:108488)\n    at F.t._callback.t.callback.t.callback (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:368:4017)\n    at F.emit (events.js:210:5)\n    at F. (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:368:16714)\n    at F.emit (events.js:210:5)\n    at IncomingMessage. (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:368:15546)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)"}"

---

### "{"stack":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1\n    at JSON.parse ()\n    at Object. (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:392:115579)\n    at C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:392:112703\n    at Object.throw (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:392:112808)\n    at s (C:\\Users\\jenny.xue.wei\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Bot Framework Composer\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\lib\\node\\index.js:392:111573)","message":"Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"}"

---

### "SyntaxError - Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I contacted with the Microsoft support team and it's LUIS portal UI issue. Now it's all working as it before.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more tag in publish profile for prediction Luis resource with name as luisResource.
Here is example:

```
"name": "composerBotName",
"environment": "test",
"luisResource": "prediction-luis-resource-name"
```

Comment: I have the same error. I put the luisResource property in the publish file but the same error keeps getting. Any other idea?